# NagiosAppender with Logback but without NSCAweb

Tags: logback, nagios, appender

Well I have a big problem because I think I've already reach the end of Internet and found nothing. I have to configure Nagios with Logback. I easily did it with Log4j but on one server there is Logback instead of Log4j. The only thing I've found is nagios appender for logback which is using nscaweb but today I've got to know that I cannot use nscaweb... So here is my question: how deep am I in this shit? Because this is another day with this problem and day by day I resolve something which turns out to be useless because somthing! What should I do to configure nagios appender with logback without using nscaweb (which installation page was deleted by the author!)?

Answer (score 0):

For your info, I emailed the NSCAWeb author, and he said the project has moved to https://github.com/smetj/nscaweb/tree/develop

He said that development version also includes some bugfixes and a more normal 
Python setup, and that he plans to release it soon.